# How is this nice D3.js scattergraph highlighting effect achieved?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, d3.js

I love the way this scatterchart highlights circles when you mouse over them: http://novus.github.com/nvd3/examples/scatterWithLegend.html

But there's a lot of code there (looks like the author has defined his/her own standard libraries) and I can't figure out exactly how the effect is achieved.

Is it something to do with the `.hover` class and the `stroke-width` property?

I'd like to achieve the same effect on my own scatter graph, although I'm using circles rather than paths, so it may not be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example, the effect seems to be realised in [scatter.js](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/scatter.js) from line 136.

Just highlighting individual circles is much easier though and doesn't need all the other stuff the example does. All you need to do is add a `mouseover` handler to the circles and (for example) increase `stroke-width`. That would look something like

```
d3.selectAll("circle").data(...).enter()
  .append(...)
  .classed("circle", true)
  .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("highlight", true); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("highlight", false); });
```

I'm assuming that a CSS class `highlight` defines the style. Alternatively, you can just use (in this example) CSS class `circle:hover` without the need for the event handlers.